# How to see query with the same SQL_TEXT but different parameter in history in v$sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check history of queries to specific table( let's call it `specific.table`) in oracle sql.
I have a query:

**Query 1**:`SELECT sql_id, sql_text FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like "%specific.table%"`

Let's say I did one query like this

**Query 2**: `SELECT * FROM specific.table WHERE specifc.table.something = :1` where `:1` is parameter.

Now I can use **Query 1** to check **Query 2** in history and it will be there. 
But then when I make **Query 2** with different bind variable, it is not visible in history returned by **Query 1**. Why the second **Query 2** is not visible? Is there a way to check parameter `:1` used in sql every time I use **Query 2**?

Edit:

Query I am using for checking bind variables:

```
SELECT * FROM v$sql_bind_capture WHERE sql_id = "id"
```

Edit 2:
Responding to Rene:

I want two make two queries like this:

```
select * from ngm_gebruiker where naam = 'A';
select * from ngm_gebruiker where naam = 'B'
```

and then check v$sql for the table:

```
SELECT sql_id, sql_text FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%ngm_gebruiker%
```

but the result is

`3   g71fx4fyyku6n   select * from ngm_gebruiker where naam = :"SYS_B_0"`

and when I check bind variable for `g71fx4fyyku6n`, I can only get `A`. 
I would like to check bind variable for both queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the last executed SQL statement and bind variable values in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707291/how-to-get-the-last-executed-sql-statement-and-bind-variable-values-in-oracle)

Comment: Actually no - I didn't clarify that, but I can check parameter used in query. The case is this when you do two same queries with different parameter, only the first query with the first parameter is visible in history.

Comment: :1 is not the parameter. It's a bind variable. I assume you want the see the actual value that is being assigned to this bind variable each time the query is being executed. The answer to that is in above link.

Comment: I have a bad nomenclature then. Anyway, when I said 'parameter', I meant bind variable. I know how to check it, but the case Is when do two same queries with different bind variable. In database I can only see first bind variable, and no second one.

Comment: What query do you expect to see? You only give an example of one query with one bind variable.

Comment: Maybe the trace option that is mentioned in the link above you will help you with that

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with three different queries on the same table:

```
select * from ngm_gebruiker;
select * from ngm_gebruiker where naam = 'Piet';
select * from ngm_gebruiker where naam = 'Piet' and idc_monitor='N';
```

Result of querying v$sql for that table:

```
SELECT sql_id, sql_text FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%ngm_gebruiker%'

2   a0q4f137bffs6   select * from ngm_gebruiker 
3   g71fx4fyyku6n   select * from ngm_gebruiker where naam = :"SYS_B_0" 
4   4vpyf8g2q711h   select * from ngm_gebruiker where naam = :"SYS_B_0" and idc_monitor=:"SYS_B_1"
```

Comment: I added example to my post.