# How to query executed script in Oracle Database with passed parameters values

Tags: sql, oracle

I was use following script to query executed sql script

```
    SELECT  * FROM (SELECT
    S.USERNAME,
    s.sid,
    s.osuser,
    t.sql_id,
    t.sql_text,
    s.sql_exec_start
--  t.*
FROM
    v$sqltext_with_newlines t,
    V$SESSION s
WHERE
    t.address = s.sql_address
    AND t.hash_value = s.sql_hash_value
    AND s.status = 'ACTIVE'
    AND s.username <> 'SYSTEM'   
    ORDER BY SQL_EXEC_START,
    s.sid,
    t.piece);
```

but it can only show the sql script with parameters name
for example :

```
select customer from customer_master where country in (:countries)
```

how can I get the parameters values for troubleshooting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last executed SQL statement and bind variable values in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707291/how-to-get-the-last-executed-sql-statement-and-bind-variable-values-in-oracle)

Comment: thanks yes, 80% good hint, but more question again. The script is provide most of bind variable & values to me, but not all !!?? some variables are missing,  same thing is those variables multiple values,

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to always capture everything, because it will create too much overhead. To perform capturing of a specific statents you'd better to set up an auditing policy. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/administering-the-audit-trail.html#GUID-9F298B8A-6196-4206-A889-A7CEB0924CF1. What it the target purpose of this script?

Comment: Hi Astentx , appreciate your reply, I'm not very familiar with this, it's quite hard to me. Can I understand that will need a special configuration , then I can get the variables with multiple values ? could you guiding me or point out which section I should study first. then I can discussing with DBA or someone else.